# Backdrop-filter: blur not working on dropdown backrgound

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a backdrop-filter: blur to my dropdown background, but it is just not working. I did the same thing with the navbar background and it works perfectly. Why doesn't it work on the dropdown as well?

HTML:

```css
#navbar #menu-buttons .cell-middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

#nav #navbar #menu-buttons .cell-middle .dropdown .dropbtn {
  padding: 44px 20px;
}

#nav #navbar #menu-buttons .cell-middle .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  filter: blur(0px);
}

#nav #navbar #menu-buttons .cell-middle .dropdown .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(253, 255, 252, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  left: -60px;
  top: 74px;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
    <img class="logo" src="qLogo.svg" alt="logo" />
    <div id="menu-buttons">
      <div class="cell-left"><a href="#">.home</a></div>
      <div class="cell-middle">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropbtn">.work</a>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="logos.html">Logo design</a>
            <a href="illustrations.html">Illustrations</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cell-right"><a href="contact.html">.contact</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can see the example here: https://codepen.io/sodelll/pen/VwbqexY

Here the image at the top (with the red div behind) is what I want to achieve and the bottom is what actually happens in my code.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post an image of what happens versus what you want to happen?  Your codepen is missing images and isn't very helpful.

Comment: I edited the post, added a photo to explain better what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

**I guess you are looking for this**

```css
  body {
background-image: url('https://cdn-media-2.freecodecamp.org/w1280/5f9c9cfc740569d1a4ca3543.jpg');
background-size: cover;
/* background-position: center; */
background-repeat: no-repeat;
     }

ul {
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 list-style: none;
 font-family: arial;
 
 
}

ul li {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 height: 45px;

 background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
 /* background-color: transparent; */ /* uncomment this to make it complete transparent*/
 opacity: .90;
 line-height: 40px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;

 
}

ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    


<ul>

   <li><a>Contact</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">User</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Phone number</a></li>
   <li><a href="">whatever</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
   


   
  
  </ul>
   <li><a>Work</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Company</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
   <li><a href="">BigComp.</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Something</a></li>
   
   
   </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

**Verify my answer if I help you**

Comment: wait for couple of minute.

Comment: I edited the post, added a photo to explain better what I need to achieve.

Comment: ook, Now it's understandable.

Comment: sorry, I take so long here I updated my Code check this.

Comment: It is not really doing what I need. I want to hover over the ".work" button in my case and a dropdown to pop up. The background of the dropdown needs to have a transparency around 50% and everything behind it to be blurred, as I showed in the photo example

Comment: sorry, I take so long again but now you all set I updated my Code and I'm sure this is what you want. Don't forget to upvote and verify my answer if it help you.